# RestKit Mapping for below Json file

Tags: ios, restkit

```
{ "lastUpdated":0, "firstItemParent":{ "title":"Item 1 title", "text":"Item 1 text", "firstItemList":[ { "title":"Kitchen" }, { "title":"Lounge" }, { "title":"Bathroom" }, { "title":"Garage" } ] } }
```

need to write RestKit mapping for this data received. Can anybody help me with this.

I tried making firstItemParent element as a class and tried firstItemList as a path nothing worked, and i am new to *restkit* mapping.

Comment: paste some code what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

To begin with first you need to create mapping model classes, as per the JSON the mapping classes and properties shown below.

```
Class ResponseModel
            @property (assign,nonatomic) int lastUpdated;
            @property (strong, nonatomic) FirstItemParent *firstItemParent;

  Class FirstItemParent
        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *firstItemList;

  Class FirstItemList
        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
```

After creating the modal classes you have to write the relation mappings to it.